# azure media services from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I find some relevant answers but none that explains if I really need all the code from the Azure Media Services teams example at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-copying-existing-blob/ 
I just want to upload a file from blob to Azure Media Services. Like this:

```
  var uploadFilePath = blobUrl;
  var uploadAsset = _context.Assets.Create(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uploadFilePath), AssetCreationOptions.None);
  var assetFile = uploadAsset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath));
  assetFile.Upload(uploadFilePath);
```

But I'm getting

> AggregateException was unhandled by user code, "An exception of type
>   'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not
>   handled in user code"

Stack trace

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.Upload(String
>   path)    at
>   UploadMediaServicesExample.Services.MediaHandler.AddFileToMediaServices(String
>   blobUrl) in
>   C:\Source\UploadMediaServicesExample\UploadMediaServicesExample\Services\MediaHandler.cs:line
>   51    at
>   UploadMediaServicesExample.Controllers.HomeController.UploadVideo(IEnumerable`1
>   file) in
>   C:\Source\UploadMediaServicesExample\UploadMediaServicesExample\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
>   24    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

Additional information: One or more errors occurred.

Here is the blob Uri which is public.. "https://mulimo.blob.core.windows.net/temporary-files/clip.mp4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asset file upload method not supporting upload from blobs. It is only working with local files. Regarding exception you should see message in inner exception message property. You can use azure media services extensions (or see how it is done there) https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services-extensions to create asset from existing blob.